# JQuery Mobile programmatically create selectmenu - styling gone

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, select

I used JQuery Mobile 1.4.5 to programmatically create a select menu. It works, however the styling is gone. If I do `$select.selectmenu()`, the styling is there, but the popup window is displayed fullscreen instead of just floating above the select widget.

```
var $select = $("<select>");
$select.attr({
     id: "selectThemes",
     "data-native-menu": false
});

$.each(settings.themes, function (index, theme) {
    var $option = $("<option>");
    $option.attr("value", theme.Theme).text(theme.Name).appendTo($select);
});

$("#divOptions").append($select);
$select.selectmenu();
```

For test purpose, I also created a static select in my HTML page and called `$select.selectmenu()` in `document.ready()`, but the styling is missing as well.

Any ideas are appreciated! :)

Comment: I just tested your code and it works. Are you sure you are including the jqm css files and running your code inside a document ready function?

Comment: Yes, I used both jquery-ui and jquery.mobile css files. Already tried deleting browser cache as well :(

Comment: Code seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/18ajezcd/ Can you edit the jsFiddle to reproduce your issue?

Comment: So the app is a C# project. There is another selectmenu in the app, which works fine, with a ´<select>´ node in the aspx page and the options are filled in the code behind with C#. I wrote my selectmenu in JS and put it in a ´<div>´ node. That's the difference. I looked at the DOM node and found that JQuery creates a ´data-role="dialog"´ for my selectmenu. Do you happen to know how I can explicitly tell JQuery to display the options as a popup?

Comment: Oh, I've found the problem. Well, it's not really a problem. The styling is correct - the selectmenu is displayed fullscreen because there are many items on the list. I didn't realize it because the scrollbar on the right side is missing. So I guess I'll just have to add the scrollbar and the problem is solved. Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styling is correct - the selectmenu is displayed fullscreen because there are many items on the list. I didn't realize it because the scrollbar on the right side is missing. I enable scrolling and the problem is solved.